# Is it safe to uninstall these packages?

Tags: apt, 18.04

Whenever I install new packages with apt, it shows a long list of packages that can be uninstalled. I don't recognize them, but based on the names them look like core components.

Can I trust apt and uninstall these, or should I keep them? If I need them, how do I stop apt from telling me about them?

```
Los paquetes indicados a continuación se instalaron de forma automática y ya no son necesarios.
  cli-common docutils-common gconf-service gconf-service-backend gconf2-common gir1.2-harfbuzz-0.0
  icu-devtools indicator-messages indicator-sound libbonobo2-0 libbonobo2-common libbonoboui2-common
  libclass-data-inheritable-perl libclass-method-modifiers-perl libcrypt-openssl-bignum-perl
  libcrypt-openssl-rsa-perl libdata-random-perl libfile-which-perl libgconf-2-4 libgd-perl libglade2-0
  libgnome-keyring-common libgnome-keyring0 libgnome2-canvas-perl libgnome2-gconf-perl
  libgnome2-wnck-perl libgnomecanvas2-0 libgnomecanvas2-common libgnomeui-common libgraphite2-dev
  libgtk2-imageview-perl libgtk2-unique-perl libgtkimageview0 libharfbuzz-gobject0
  libhttp-server-simple-perl libicu-le-hb0 libiculx60 libido3-0.1-0 libimage-magick-perl
  libimage-magick-q16-perl libllvm7 libllvm7:i386 libmouse-perl libnet-dropbox-api-perl
  libnet-oauth-perl liborbit-2-0 libpanel-applet3 libpath-class-perl libpcre16-3 libpcre3-dev
  libpcre32-3 libpcrecpp0v5 libproc-processtable-perl libproc-simple-perl libsort-naturally-perl
  libunique-1.0-0 libwnck-common libwnck22 libwww-mechanize-perl libx11-protocol-other-perl
  libxcb-xtest0 lsdvd pkg-config sgml-base xml-core
```

I think this started hpenning because a while back I accidently removed the system Python from my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. I managed to recover after consulting Ask Ubuntu (don't remember which questions) for these commands (from my bash history):

```bsh
sudo apt remove python3.6 # oops!
sudo apt-get install python3-all
sudo apt-get install gnome-terminal
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
sudo apt-get install xorg
sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop
```

Comment: My interface language is Spanish. Feel free to translate the message from apt to English if you know what it should say.

Comment: You could use `LANG=C sudo apt update` or `LANG=C sudo apt upgrade`, etc to generate output in English.

Comment: There are a few important Gnome packages in there; looks like you tried to remove Gnome. Be SURE you have `ubuntu-desktop` installed, then let apt remove the list.

Answer (score 0):

Leave the packages listed in the terminal message alone for now until you're sure that you know what you're doing.

Your terminal message says `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:` You can remove these packages automatically by running `sudo apt autoremove` but it's not a good idea to remove these packages until you're sure that you don't need to reinstall packages that were removed as a consequence of accidentally removing the system Python from Ubuntu 18.04. If the packages listed after `The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:` are dependencies of any packages that you subsequently reinstalled, these packages will stop generating package management messages in the terminal.